# Change state from primary page when i activated button. React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have simple task, create todo app in react with 3 pages. 1st page is todos (list of all todos),sec page is page/create. And i want to  know wow can I do that. I never try to do something like this. If you can pls help."

Comment: You shouldn't have any problem finding tutorials on how to set up a basic react app with a react router. There are boiler plate seed projects that you can get up and running in minutes also like create-react-app. This whole question is far too broad as outlined in the [help]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.